# How to override default context menu action in Android's web view

Tags: android, android-webview, contextmenu, android-developer-api

I am trying to override the menu item (web search) after long press in any text. 
The default menu contains "`select`", "`select all`" and "`search`" in icons. When I check search length icon, it lead me to google search with selected text.

I want to override that action. i.e when I click search lens I want to implement my custom action.

Please help me.

Please refer image below:

[image]

Comment: There is no easier way to do this. If you have to do that you need to create a custom webview class and get the inflate to work with your menu